# Is there progress in interested variable mechanism in process synchronization in operating system?

Tags: process, operating-system, synchronization, critical-section

Two processes, P1 and P2, need to access a critical section of code. Consider the following synchronization construct used by the processes:

```
/*  P1   */
while (true) {
    wants1 = true;
    while (wants2 == true);
    /* Critical Section */
    wants1 = false;
}
/* Remainder section */
/*  P2   */
while (true) {
    wants2 = true;
    while (wants1 == true);
    /* Critical Section */
    wants2=false;
}
/* Remainder section */
```

Here, wants1 and wants2 are shared variables,

My question is to argue on PROGRESS.

A case can be possible when P1 wants to enter in the critical section and set its interested variable to true and checks whether the interested variable of P2 is true. Here, (consider )P2's interest variable to be True hence P1 will get stuck in the while loop and waits for P2 become uninterested. Since, P2 still stuck in the while loop waiting for the P1’s interested variable to become false. Therefore, both the processes are waiting for each other and none of them is getting into the critical section..

DEFINITION of progress:If no process is executing in its critical section and some processes wish to enter their critical sections, then only those processes that are not executing in their remainder section can participate in deciding which will enter its critical section next, AND THIS SELECTION CANNOT BE POSTPONED INDEFINITELY.

SO WHY EVERYWHERE IT IS WRITTEN PROGRESS IS THERE?

In the case when both wants1 and wants2 are true it will indefinitely be postponed then why progress is there?

Comment: That code is just broken.  Only a glance shows that both 'wants' could be set true and then both processes loop forever:(

Comment: Yes. It is broken. There is a clear deadlock(livelock). But does progress exists?
I know this cannot be used. But I just want to clarify my understanding of the topic progress.
Both processes enter the entry section of the critical section and competes to enter the critical section indefinitely so I think progress doesn't exist but on some online sources, i have found that authors have written it exists without explaining why.

Comment: I do not think that livelock counts as making forward progress:)